# Why is this code still adding blank lines between data in a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, temporary-files

The following code is intended to remove tags from a csv file. Tags are labelled as follows (the tag here is hot as an example): tag,hot
It iterates through the current csv file, writing every line to a temporary file except the tag that needs to be removed, then renames the temporary file on top of the original. Currently, it adds whitespace between every line in the original, eg:

```
tag,tag1
tag,tag2
tag,tag3
tag,tag4
tag,tag5
```

goes to the following if tag3 was passed as the tag to be removed:

```
tag,tag1

tag,tag2


tag,tag4

tag,tag5
```

As can be seen an extra line is where tag3 would have been, as well as there being blank lines between every other line. I have seen other threads that suggested adding `newline=''` to when the files are opened, but I have done this and it still does not solve the problem (although there was actually more whitespace before, with 2 lines between every value rather than 1). Not sure why this hasn't fixed it.

Code:

```
tempfile = NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w", delete=False, newline='')
CSVpart = imageNumber + ".csv"
lowercase = tag.lower()
filePath = os.path.join(os.curdir, "static", "csv", CSVpart)
if os.path.isfile(filePath):
    with open(filePath, 'r', newline='') as csvfile, tempfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        writer = csv.writer(tempfile)
        for row in reader:
            if row != ['tag', lowercase]:
                writer.writerow(row)
            else:
                removed = True //ignore, this makes sense in context
shutil.move(tempfile.name, filePath)
```

I created the following, which works. Cannot figure out what is different about it:

```
import shutil, csv, os
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile


tempfile = NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w", delete=False, newline='')
tagToRemove = "hot"
filePath = os.path.join(os.curdir, "test.csv")
with open(filePath, 'r', newline='') as csvfile, tempfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer = csv.writer(tempfile)
    for row in reader:
        if row != ['tag', tagToRemove]:
            writer.writerow(row)

shutil.move(tempfile.name, filePath)
```

Comment: I can't see a problem, please try to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MichaelButscher I've added something at the bottom to this effect, but it works. Cannot figure out the difference between them.

Comment: So the bug is probably in the part of the original code you didn't show here.